# For a magically shorter tabaxi, which stats do I adjust?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, skills, ability-scores, tabaxi

I know that an average tabaxi race is medium about 6ft tall. But I want a shorter more stubby cat for my character (a lvl. 1 magician tabaxi with a background of guild merchant. *in short, the backstory I have planned for him is that he stumbled on a spellbook during his work, and being a noob messed up the spell which resulted in shrinking him a bit*. he was kind of supposed to be a dumb character)

If I make it around 3.5 - 4 feet tall, obviously a few skills, traits and abilities should be leveled down accordingly. But which?

I'm guessing lower agility, less speed, shorter reach of melee attacks, no heavy weapons..

Am I missing anything else?

Comment: So you are you changing him to a small sized humanoid rather then a medium?

Answer (score 3):

You could compare to the Halfling race in the PHB, which is an official race that has only a small size.

The only traits of this race that are clearly down to their size is their speed of 25 feet and possibly "Halfling nimbleness" that allows them to move through a space of a larger creature.

(You mention lower agility but halflings actually get a +2 to Dex which, if nothing else, implies that size and agility are not necessarily related).

There are already rules in the Weapons section of the PHB regarding small creatures (a small creature has disadvantage with any weapon designated as 'heavy')